# count records in get method REst Apex Services Json Response

Tags: rest, salesforce, apex

```
    @RestResource(urlMapping='/sg/0.1/subscription/')
global with sharing class SubsRecord1 {
    Public Integer count {get;set;}
    @HttpGet
    global static List<ONB2__Subscription__c> getSubsById() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        List<ONB2__Subscription__c>  result =  [select id , name FROM ONB2__Subscription__c where ONB2__Status__c =:'Active'];
        return result;
    }
}
```

1. I want the Json response something like this { "ONB2__Subscription__c": "[[n]]"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below sample code, hope this helps

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/sg/0.1/subscription/')
    global with sharing class SubsRecord1 {

    @HttpGet
    global static void getSubsById() {
        RestRequest request = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse response =RestContext.response;
        AggregateResult result   =  [select count(id)subcount FROM ONB2__Subscription__c where ONB2__Status__c =:'Active'];
        response.statusCode = 200;
        string jsonResponse = '{"ONB2__Subscription__c":'+'"'+result.get('subcount')+'"'+'}';
        response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(jsonResponse);
        return;
    }
}
```